# Looping through all Controls [MaterialSkin] (C#)

Tags: c#, foreach, material-design

I am making a general Software and in it I added some labels (I can't tell more.. xD)
So, I wanted to loop through every Control in my Form or at least all the Labels... I have tried

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    //item.Font.Size = 11f;
    c.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

But I think it only loops to the `MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialTabControl`

because when i Try to run any code with MaterialLabel..etc

```
    foreach (MaterialLabel c in this.Controls)
    {
        //item.Font.Size = 11f;
        c.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
```

it tells me

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialTabControl' to type 'MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialLabel'.
```

I need help Please Help me :)
I am not a very Good Programmer... So please help

Now going to play Left 4 Dead xD

Comment: `foreach (MaterialLabel c in this.Controls.OfType<MaterialLabel>())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before changing any property check if it is type of `MaterialLabel`.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if(c.GetType()==typeof(MaterialLabel))
    {
         c.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
         c.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

or as LarsTech said:

```
foreach (MaterialLabel c in this.Controls.OfType<MaterialLabel>())
{
     c.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    c.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: I think it's not even reaching the other Controls... it ends on the Tabcontrol and that's it... it is not working with a loop but if I use it normally it does works
Can you also tell me how to make it bold because when i use `c.Font.Bold = true;` it says it cannot be assigned because it is readonly

Comment: @RajaBilal I edited my answer. please have a look at it

Comment: I told you It's not working... the Code is not working... read my comment again please

Comment: and I told you that I have changed my answer. `item.Font = new Font(item.Font, FontStyle.Bold);`

Comment: `c.GetType() == typeof(MaterialLabel)` is not a good way to do the type check,

Answer (score 1):

few options...

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls)
{
    if(c is MaterialLabel)
    {
         var i = (MaterialLabel)c;
         i.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
         i.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

...

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls)
{
    //slightly faster than the first version but won't work with struct
    var i = c as MaterialLabel; 
    if(i != null)
    {
         i.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
         i.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

...

```
//cleanest
foreach (var c in this.Controls.OfType<MaterialLabel>())
{
     c.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
     c.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Non of these are working... Is it because i am using a custom font and when I set the color by default it changed automatically to black... even the file + the complied exe but when I do it in the file like `conditionlbl.ForeColor = Color.White;` It works... but it's not working through a loop and not by the default settings

Comment: I use the method provided here http://hongouru.blogspot.com/2010/10/c-how-to-add-fonts-ttf-true-type-fonts.html to use a custom Font...

Comment: It might also be because i am using a material Label and it does not exist in the System's Control library... they are inside the Tab Control and inside 2 to 3 Panels ... and the only get's till the tab control... not more inside i mean inside those panels...